# How to change the url using django process_request .

Tags: python, django, url, middleware

This is my code :

```
class MobileMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.path.startswith('/core/mypage/'):
            request.path='/core/mypage/?key=value'
            print request.path,'aaaa'
```

I want to add a param `key` when the page url is `/core/mypage/`,

and the url of the web browser would be changed to `http:www.ss.com/core/mypage/?key=value`

However,  the url in the browser is not changed.

What can I do?

Answer (score 17):

For googlers - I tested with request.path_info. If you want to change URL in middlware, change request.path_info in [process_request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process_request).

```
request.path_info = <change request.path_info>
```

Please Note that I do not suggest or forbid to use this. I'm just saying if you want to change urls, this is the way you can.

Comment: Although, this does actually make the right request, the url in the browser didn't change. I don't think it will without a redirect.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `HttpRequest.path` is a plain attribute. Changing it does not make any new instructions for the browser. You're probably looking for the [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) method which will actually force the browser to go somewhere else.

Comment: but this will Consume a lot of performance, it is a 302 jump ,can we change the django core code  ?

Comment: There are only two ways to change what the client's browser shows as a  URL (which is what I think you're asking for). The first is to use redirect or headers to actually send them to another location. The second is to use JS to redirect them. Either way you're talking about a page refresh. That's just how browsers work.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/core/mypage/?key=value')
```

Comment: but this will Consume a lot of performance, it is a 302 jump ,can we change the django core code  ?

Comment: with the logic in the question, this will be a infinite loop of redirects since the request still starts with 'core/mypage'

Answer (score 1):

The request.path_info did not change the url in the browser address bar for me but this redirect did:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


class DomainRedirectMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):

        if request.path.startswith('/core/mypage/') and not request.GET:
            return redirect('/core/mypage/?key=value')  # works!
            #request.path_info = '/core/mypage/?key=value'  # works, but does not change url in browser address bar
```

Django also provides a "Redirects App" since Django 1.3, which includes the following middleware: 'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware' . See the [redirects app documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/redirects/), it lets you create redirects from the admin interface.

I tried the same redirect using the app and it worked. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but try something like `request.GET["key"] = val`

**Edit:** or maybe use `request.path_info` instead of `request.path`